# Get items from child categories sql query

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have the below database structure:

```
[CATEGORY]
category_id
parent(default 0)
title

[PRODUCT]
product_id
title

[PRODUCT_TO_CATEGORY]
product_id
category_id
```

Sample data for **CATEGORY**:

```
1   0   TV
2   1   PLASMA
3   1   LED
.   .   ...
```

Sample data for **PRODUCT**:

```
1   Sony
2   Sharp
3   Samsung
.   ...
```

Sample data for **PRODUCT_TO_CATEGORY**:

```
1(Sony)    1(TV)
2(Sharp)   2(PLASMA)
3(Samsung) 2(PLASMA)
```

First of all I want to ask if my structure is good. For example should I assign both category and subcategory ids to each product or a single category works good?

Then based to the assumption of each product belonging to one category and a category may have a parent or more, how can I retrieve products for current and every child category ?
For example hitting TV category should list Sony,Sharp and Samsung and not just Sony item.

Comment: No. You don't embed parent/child in the product. That'd open the possibility of a bad relationship being added in, e.g. ("Game Consoles", "Dell") or ("Innovative Companies", "Microsoft"). Embed ONE category only, from which it's trivial to retrieve the associated parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> parent(default 0)

Use NULL instead of 0. This will allow you to use a proper FOREIGN KEY (as illustrated below).

---

> should I assign both category and subcategory ids to each product

You shouldn't. Just assign the most specific sub-category that applies to that product. All the super-categories can be inferred from the hierarchy defined in the `CATEGORY` table, so storing (even one of) them in the product is redundant.

Such redundancies can sometimes be justified for performance reasons, but then you have to balance them with **data consistency**. In this case, there is no good declarative way to keep the redundant data synchronized with the "master" data - you'd have to do it through triggers or (god forbid) application code and you'll probably introduce concurrency bugs in doing so, unless you consider your locking strategy *very, very* carefully.

---

> Then based to the assumption of each product belonging to one category...

This assumption makes your model incorrect. To correctly model this N:1 relationship, you do not need the junction table `PRODUCT_TO_CATEGORY`, you simply need a foreign key between product and category:

[image]

NOTE: Make the `PRODUCT.CATEGORY_ID` NULL-able if you want to allow category-less products (i.e. your relationship is actually N:0..1 instead of N:1).

And your data would look like:

```
CATEGORY:

1   TV      NULL
2   PLASMA  1
3   LED     1

PRODUCT:

1   Sony    1 (TV)
2   Sharp   2 (PLASMA)
3   Samsung 2 (PLASMA)
```

---

> how can I retrieve products for current and every child category?

First identify all categories that belong to the desired "sub-tree", then retrieve products connected to them. In this case, searching for all TVs can be done like this:

1. Get the ID of the "top" category you are searching for: 1 (TV).

   `SELECT CATEGORY_ID FROM CATEGORY WHERE TITLE = 'TV'`
2. Get the IDs of all the child categories: 2 (PLASMA) and 3 (LED).

   `SELECT CATEGORY_ID FROM CATEGORY WHERE PARENT_ID IN (1)`
3. Repeat the step (2) until you reach the "bottom" of the hierarchy:

   `SELECT CATEGORY_ID FROM CATEGORY WHERE PARENT_ID IN (2, 3)`

   The above query will return an empty result set for your example data, so you'll know you  can stop. In more elaborate hierarchies, you may need to repeat the above query several times, always replacing the IN list with the most recently retrieved "layer" of categories.

   Beware of infinite iteration if you happen to have a cycle in your data!
4. Get all the products connected to any of the identified categories: 1 (TV), 2 (PLASMA) and 3 (LED).

   `SELECT * FROM PRODUCT WHERE CATEGORY_ID IN (1, 2, 3)`

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't support the kind of recursive query that would allow you to do all that in a single database round-trip.

Answer (score 0):

Read about nested sets for grouping products.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model

It allows you to create a nice structure in a relational database to assign products to categories.  Much better than the typical child->parent model most people come up with.

Comment: Interesting. But I can t see why to use this technique, when you give the administration of creating those categories to a user. The categories and subcategories are not fixed but a part of a CMS and it seems that updating and calculating for this technique could be a mess..

Comment: You can easily create a UI for a user to create/manage categories and then map products using that approach. It's especially nice because you can map one product to a parent category and none of the children. Also you can map one product to a child category and it automatically appears in all parents. I've used it successfully _with_ user assignment for an online auction site, which mapped products to categories.